# AngularJS - How to pass data to a controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm having a hard time passing data to a controller. My scenario is that I have a function that gets a json object and I need to pass that object to a controller that does the rest of the work. Below is what I'm working with:

Getting the data before DOM loads and save it in the `Data` variable.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Consultant%20Profile')/items?$filter=ID%20eq%20"+curItemId,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function(data){
        Data = data.d.results; //global variable that I want to pass.
        console.log(Data);

    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log("something is not right with - ", data)
    }   
   });
```

This is the controller that I would like to pass `Data` to.

```
var app = angular.module("contactApp",[]);
app.value('listData', Data);
app.controller('ContactController',['listData','$scope','$http',function(listData,$scope,$http){
        console.log(listData);
        //Do something here...  
});
```

I'm trying to use `value()` but getting an error if I pass in anything other than a string. So if `Data = "Sometext"` it would console out that text but if it's an object it doesn't work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but is there a better way of doing this!?

Comment: why don't you use the $http service from angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup as Rafael has mentioned try using the $http service from Angular

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I can get the data but I can't pass it. Angular doesn't like the data $ajax returns!?

Comment: what error are you getting? what type of var are you trying to pass?

Comment: I think I got it! The call is async so the variable was not defined when the controller was fired off (It takes the call longer to return data, same behavior using $http). I'm exploring angular's factory to get the data and then inject it to the controller.